# moveRowAtIndexPath cell numbering

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a custom UITableViewCell called CustomCell which has a UILabel in it which it is supposed to show the current index number + 1 (It is a queue of things to do).

I am using the setEditing method to allow the users to move cells around however I just cannot get the cells to be numbered correctly (in order) with the following code. Basically I am just trying to access the cells in the region the method parameters are passed but the numbers are simply returning out of order. What am I doing wrong here?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {
    [queuedToDoArray moveObjectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row toIndex:toIndexPath.row];

    NSIndexPath *lowerIndexPath = (fromIndexPath.row < toIndexPath.row ? fromIndexPath : toIndexPath);
    NSIndexPath *higherIndexPath = (fromIndexPath.row > toIndexPath.row ? fromIndexPath : toIndexPath);

    //Update all the queue numbers in between moved indexes
    for (int i = lowerIndexPath.row; i <= higherIndexPath.row; i++) {
        NSIndexPath *currentIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
        CustomCell *currentCell = [todoTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:currentIndexPath];
        [currentCell.queueNumber setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", currentIndexPath.row + 1]];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not configure your tableview cell a.k.a `customCell` in `moveRowAtIndexPath` method, instead, just updating the data-model array for the relocated row.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath {
    NSString *stringToMove = [self.queuedToDoArray objectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];
    [self.queuedToDoArray removeObjectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];
    [self.queuedToDoArray insertObject:stringToMove atIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];
}
```

After that, just call `[self.tableView reloadData]` and it will automatically do that for you.

Please check out the [Apple Developer Document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageReorderRow/ManageReorderRow.html) for more details.

Edit:

A better solution is just reloading the relative sections or rows as @Paulw11 commented.

Comment: Rather than reloading the whole table, you can just reload the affected rows

Comment: @Paulw11 Good point, reloading the specific rows is a better way.